# Inequality in Sobolev Space Involving Time

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In Evans PDE book, I have the next Theorem:

If $u \in W^{1,p}([0,T],X)$ then:

i) $u(t) = u(s) + \int_{s}^tu'(\tau) d\tau $ for $0\leq s\leq t \leq T$

ii) $\max_{0\leq t \leq T} \| u(t)\|_X \leq C \| u \|_{W^{1,p}([0,T],X)}$

With $C$ a constant depending of $T$, now my question is how can I prove ii) using i)?

Answer (score 2):

First,  from (i) we get
$$
\|u(t)-u(s)\|\le\int_s^t \|u'(\tau)\|d\tau,
$$
which proves that $u\in C([0,T],X)$. It remains to show the norm bound.

Second, integrating
$$
u(t)-u(s) = \int_s^t u'(\tau)d\tau.
$$
with respect to $s$ from $0$ to $T$ yields
$$
\int_0^T u(t)-u(s)ds = \int_0^T\int_s^t u'(\tau)d\tau\, ds\\
= \int_0^t\int_s^t u'(\tau)d\tau\, ds - \int_t^T\int_t^s u'(\tau)d\tau\, ds\\
=\int_0^t\int_0^\tau u'(\tau)ds\,d\tau - \int_t^T\int_\tau^T u'(\tau)ds\,d\tau,\\
=\int_0^t\tau u'(\tau)d\tau - \int_t^T(T-\tau) u'(\tau)ds\,d\tau,\\
$$ 
hence
$$
\|\int_0^T u(t)-u(s)ds\|\le 2 T\int_0^T \|u'(\tau)\|d\tau.
$$
This shows
$$
\|u(t)\| \le \frac1T\|\int_0^T u(t)-u(s)ds\| + \frac1T \|\int_0^T u(s)ds\|
\le 2 \int_0^T \|u'(\tau)\|d\tau + \frac1T \int_0^T \|u(s)\|ds\\
\le 2 \|u'\|_{L^1(0,T;X)} + T^{-1} \|u\|_{L^1(0,T;X)}.
$$
The bound follows from the embedding $L^p(0,T)\hookrightarrow L^1(0,T)$.

Comment: Thanks ! I got the last inequality but I forget the embedding !!!